# How to change this href inside echo?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a php variable to add a href value for a link in an echo statement.

Here's a simplified version of the code I want to use. I know that I can't just add the variable into the echo statement, but I can't seem to find an example anywhere that works.

```
<a href="<?=base_index();?>list-job-order?<?=$param;?>" class="btn btn-success btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i> Back</a>
```

Comment: send full file content what you want

Comment: Are you printing this with `echo '<a href...> [..] Back</a>'`?

Comment: yes i want printing this with echo

Comment: You can't echo within an echo. But you can *concatenate* strings together. `echo '<a href="'.base_index().'"list-job-order?'.$param.'" class...` and so on. See the difference? :)

Comment: yeah i see , thank you :)

Comment: echo "<a href=' ".variable_name.' ">Back</a>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will work. kindly use this code in your .php file.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_index();?>list-job-order?<?php echo $param;?>" class="btn btn-success btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i> Back</a>
```

and if you want to echo in  then use this

```
<?php
echo "<a href=" . base_index() . "list-job-order?" . $param . " class='btn btn-success btn-flat'><i class='fa fa-step-backward'></i> Back</a>";

 ?>
```